pseudodifferential operator, singular integral operator, and oscillatory integral operator
I am confused by the three integral operators in the title.
I am currently reading a note found online, and from its development, my impression is that the kernels of pseudodifferential operators have to be interpreted as oscillatory integrals. However, I have also noted in Wikipedia that

Pseudo-differential operators can be represented by kernels. The singularity of the kernel on the diagonal depends on the degree of the corresponding operator. In fact, if the symbol satisfies the above differential inequalities with $m ≤ 0$, it can be shown that the kernel is a singular integral kernel.

However, the definition of singular integral never appears in the note I am reading (it looks like different people have different emphasis on the ideas of pseudodifferential operators). So is there a containment relationship in studying those three types of operators? Or do they simply have certain intersections?

You define PDO's via Oscillatory integrals and in that sense to some extent (details required) a PDO is a special case of oscillatory integral operator. I am not familiar with singular integral operators, but looking at this it seems like a PDO (using its kernel) is yet, another special case of singular integral operators.
